# ModalBox - FancyBox Plugin issue on Google Chrome - Uncaught TypeError: url has no method 'click'

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, joomla, click, fancybox

I tried the click method to auto load modal Box, works in FF and IE but in chrome it throws me below error -

> Uncaught TypeError: Object http://my_url?ml=1 **has no method 'click'**

First i initialize fancy box using init method. Then, I have two fancy Box links, i am trying to invoke second link using :

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     jQuery("a.modalizer_link")[1].click();
 });
```

Anybody any Suggestions on getting it to work in chrome?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT, FancyBox adds a method to elements selected by jQuery (by extending the global jQuery selector), which allows you to start a FancyBox programatically.

```
$("a.modalizer_link")[1].fancybox({
    'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
    'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
    'speedIn'       :   600, 
    'speedOut'      :   200, 
    'overlayShow'   :   false
});
```

Adapted from the official FancyBox documentation [here](http://fancybox.net/howto).

I would advise against attempting to trigger an event in this case, when what you really want to do is open the modal box.